# Use facet_grid for pairwise value (heatmap) visualization in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, heatmap, facet

I have data containing pairwise numerical data for 10 samples:

```
data = dget(url("https://git.io/vCTpG"))
```

The data looks like this:

```
sampleB  sampleA  ol   labelA  labelB  facetA  facetB
2409     2409     100  2409|B  2409|B  B       B
2409     2413     0    2413|A  2409|B  A       B
2409     2414     0    2414|A  2409|B  A       B
2409     2417     0    2417|C  2409|B  C       B
2409     2411     0    2411|A  2409|B  A       B
2409     2418     0    2418|B  2409|B  B       B
2409     2416     0    2416|C  2409|B  C       B
2409     2412     4    2412|B  2409|B  B       B
2409     2415     0    2415|C  2409|B  C       B
2409     2410     19   2410|A  2409|B  A       B
...      ...      ...  ...     ...     ...     ...
```

I want to visualize the `ol` values in a heat map:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x=labelA, y=labelB)) + 
  geom_tile(mapping = aes(fill=ol)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image: plot without facet]

Now I'd like to structure the 10 by 10 heat map by a category each sample is associated with, namely `A,B` or `C` in this example. However, if I use facet_grid ...

```
last_plot() + facet_grid(facetA~facetB)
```

[image: plot with facet]

... this results in a 30 by 30 rather than in a 10 by 10 heat map which is subdivided into 3 categories (still showing only 100 values though). I remember having fixed this using

```
last_plot() + facet_grid(facetA~facetB, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

in the past, however, I can't reproduce this anymore. The desired solution would look like this (this was gimped, not ggplot generated):

[image]

I.e. a reordered, grouped 10 by 10 matrix.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you're expecting to see? Seems pretty correct: your total picture is a sum of all faceted pictures. What do you expect to see e.g. for `2409|B` on a facet A vs. facet C? Naturally, it's blank.

Comment: @tonytonov I added a manually created image to better explain the desired result

Comment: interesting.. changing the facet order gets you close `last_plot()  + facet_grid(facetB~facetA, scales = "free")`

Comment: @user20650 Wow, that's actually what I wanted... But... why?

Comment: I dont know....hopefully @tonytonov or another ggplot user has an answer

Comment: @user20650 You care to answer the question? With an additional `data$facetB = factor(data$facetB, levels = rev(levels(data$facetA)))` it generates exactly the plot I wanted...

Comment: or also use `,as.table=FALSE` .

Comment: Feel free to write it as an answer, but its probably worth leaving open to try and get an explanation for the behaviour.

Comment: I suspect it's a minor bug (or rather inconsistency) within ggplot, probably introduced rather recently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `facet_wrap()` instead of `facet_grid()` or change the order of the facets in `facet_grid()` as suggested in the comments.

The reason is that, by definition, `facet_grid` does not allow y-axes limits to be different across panels in the same row. In other words, all three panels in the top row must have the same y limits, all three panels in the second row must have the same y limits, etc. Adding `scales = "free_y"` means that the first row is allowed to have different y limits from the second row (but within a given row, all panels must always have the same y limits). In your example, when you use

```
facet_grid(facetA ~ facetB, scales = "free")
```

you are forcing `ggplot` to use all of the y values for all rows; eg the left panel in the top row must contain the value `2418|B` because that value is present in the middle panel of the top row. Reversing the order of facets happens to do the job in this case because of the structure of your data. 
(I'm just giving an example for the y axis, but the same holds for the x axis limits when using `scales = "free_x"`.)

If you want to have different x and y scales for each and every panel, independently of the ones next to it, you will need to use `facet_wrap`.

*Edit*
A more detailed explanation of how to get the figure you want. Going back to your specific example, reversing your facets will give

```
p <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x=labelA, y=labelB)) + 
    geom_tile(mapping = aes(fill=ol)) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black") + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
    facet_grid(facetB ~ facetA, scales = "free")
p
```

[image]

This contains all the panels you want. To get the order you are asking for is simply a matter of rearranging the rows. This can be done by setting the order of the levels of `facetB` (*edit*: or, as @user20650 suggested in the comments, by setting `as.table=FALSE` `in facet_grid()`):

```
data1 <- data    
data1$facetB <- factor(data1$facetB, levels = c("C", "B", "A"))
p %+% data1
```

[image]

Comment: That's not what I want, I want the figure as illustrated in the end of my question. And as already pointed out by user20650, simply swapping the two facet variables in the formula solves the problem. I filed a bug report.

Comment: @barbaz I tried to explain that this is not a bug and works as intended, and why you got different x and y axes when using facets in that order (which was what your discussion in the comments was about, an explanation of this behaviour). Once you reverse the order of facets, getting the figure as you showed is a matter of re-arranging the rows - I updated the answer with more details

Comment: Hi Konvas, I think you can get the order of the panels by using the `as.table` argument ... `facet_grid(facetB ~ facetA, scales = "free", as.table=FALSE)`